# How to use a function for two different lists

Tags: python, list

```
def apply_vowel_harmony(word, suffix):
    vowels = "aeıioöuü"
    last_word_vowel = None
    last_suffix_vowel = None

    # find last vowel in word and suffix
    for i in range(len(word) - 1, -1, -1):
        if word[i] in vowels:
            last_word_vowel = word[i]
            break

    for i in range(len(suffix) - 1, -1, -1):
        if suffix[i] in vowels:
            last_suffix_vowel = suffix[i]
            break

    # apply vowel harmony rules
    if last_suffix_vowel == 'a' and last_word_vowel in 'aıou':
        return word + 'a' + suffix
    elif last_suffix_vowel == 'e' and last_word_vowel in 'eiöü':
        return word + 'e' + suffix
    elif last_suffix_vowel == 'i' and last_word_vowel in 'ei':
        return word + 'i' + suffix
    elif last_suffix_vowel == 'ı' and last_word_vowel in 'aı':
        return word + 'ı' + suffix
    elif last_suffix_vowel == 'u' and last_word_vowel in 'ou':
        return word + 'u' + suffix
    elif last_suffix_vowel == 'ü' and last_word_vowel in 'öü':
        return word + 'ü' + suffix
    else:
        return word + suffix
```

I wrote down a code for vowel harmony. I want to use it in a scenario according to some words with some suffixes like that:

```
verbs = ["al", "gel"]
suffix = ["iyor", "ıyor", "uyor", "üyor"]

YOR_verbs = []
for unit1 in verbs:
    for unit2 in suffix:
        YOR_verbs.append(unit1 + " " + unit2)
print(YOR_verbs)
['alıyor', 'geliyor']
```

What kind of a way should I follow to get the result of print(YOR_verbs)?

Comment: Instead of appending a concatenated string of `unit1` and `unit2`. Why not call your function there? Like so: `YOR_verbs.append(apply_vowel_harmony(unit1,unit2))`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @MarceloPaco I tried it but you can see the result, here:
['aliyor', 'alıyor', 'aluyor', 'alüyor', 'geliyor', 'gelıyor', 'geluyor', 'gelüyor', 'oliyor', 'olıyor', 'oluyor', 'olüyor', 'öliyor', 'ölıyor', 'öluyor', 'ölüyor']

Basically, it seems like it just merge two lists

Comment: So do you want to do `YOR_verbs = [apply_vowel_harmony(v, s) for v, s in zip(verbs, suffix)]`?

Comment: @Timus Yes exactly. I want to use the function while merging verbs and suffixes to get a list according to the rule on the function